# how to not go with doing nothing

Tags: python

I am a bit new to python
so going from sign to sign (included) which is not that obvious with all the line in multiple, and do it again for all the other lines in a .txt file with python it's probably triggered
for example like this:

```
-before:
qqaqz-ilkds-jioes-islkd:peoiflsirc
esoij-skfjs-lkdfv-xeiro:gggggggggg
etc..
-after:
qqaqz-ilkds-jioes-islkd
esoij-skfjs-lkdfv-xeiro
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you should look at the `split()`

Comment: I rollbacked the question to its original form. Please do not deface your post after people have already made effort to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split method and get the first element:

```py
fin = open('input.txt', 'r')
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in fin:
   fout.write(line.split(':')[0] + '\n')

fout.close()
fin.close()
```

Comment: Glad it has been useful

Answer (score 0):

Put the content in abc.txt
Please use this code:

```
with open("abc.txt") as f:
    line=f.readline()
    while line:
        print(line[0:line.find(':')])    
        line=f.readline()
```